# Docker compose redundancy?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am following [the tutorial here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) and I am not sure I understand why *flask* and *redis* are pipped from the Dockerfile but also made available from docker-compose.yml.

I thought that **Compose** was used to merge multiple images and that these merged images were referred to, or say called vi the docker-compose.yml.

So my understanding was that **Compose** would install *flask* and *redis* via their own image and merge them in a single container. Though it does not seem to be what is going on, as *flask* and *redis* are also installed via the **pip** command...

Any idea of what is going on here?

Thanks,

Antoine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of Compose is incorrect. It does not merge images.

Compose manages separate containers that together form an application. There should be one image for the redis server, and another for the web application that uses flask. Each image is used to create a container, so you end up with two containers.

`pip install redis` does not install the "redis server", it installs the python client which is used to make requests to the redis server.

Comment: Hum, this is a major paradigm shift indeed... So does that mean that if I am developing a big application that has many dependencies (all with different complex ways to install) and a large testing framework, then the best practise is to capture the code clone, dependencies install (or compilation) and test framework installation into a large Dockerfile?

Comment: The many dependencies I use virtually all have their respective docker image, But if I understood you well, in order to get my dependencies all working together, I need to choose dependency image (i.e. the more complex one) as the base image and integrate the other dependencies by hand (in addition to the code clone and test framework installation)? Is that right?

Comment: Alternatively, would you clone the code on the host rather than in the container (and mount the host folder as a volume in the container)?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by dependencies. If they are code dependencies (libraries that are required to build the binary) then yes they would be part of the Dockerfile. If they are "service" dependencies (other processes that need to be run), like a database, then they would be in separate Dockerfiles.

Comment: I always `git clone` (or whatever SVC you use) on the host, and use `COPY` or a `volume` to add the code to the container.

Comment: If you're working with web applications, where you might have tasks that require node+npm+bower, and some that require the backend language dependencies I would probably have two separate Dockerfiles for that.